# KeyboardAvoidingView does not work with Field in redux-form

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, redux-form

I used KeyboardAvoidingView from 'react-native'. Once I focus on input field, the keyboard is still overlay the input. Below is my code

```
    <KeyboardAvoidingView keyboardVerticalOffset = {0} style = {{ flex: 1 }} behavior = "padding" >  
        <ScrollView>
             <View style={styles.formGroup}>
                   <Text style={styles.labelGroup}>{Question.howToReachJobVacancy }</Text>
                   <Field
                        component={CustomTextInput}
                        multiline={true}
                        numberOfLines={2}
                        placeholder='ចុចទីនេះដើម្បីសរសេរចម្លើយ'
                    />
              </View>
        </ScrollView>

     </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Here is my CustomTextInput.

```
        <TextField {...inputProps} 
           value={input.value}
           onChangeText={ input.onChange }
           onBlur={input.onBlur}
           onFocus={input.onFocus}
           multiline={true}
           labelHeight={0}}/>
```

I would like to fix iOS keyboard popup over the input field.

Comment: You need to use KeyboardAvoidingView instead of KeyboardAvoiding in `render()`

Comment: You're right. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={(Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : null)} style={{ flex: 0 }}>
        <ScrollView>
             <View style={styles.formGroup}>
                   <Text style={styles.labelGroup}>{Question.howToReachJobVacancy }</Text>
                   <Field
                        component={CustomTextInput}
                        multiline={true}
                        numberOfLines={2}
                        placeholder='ចុចទីនេះដើម្បីសរសេរចម្លើយ'
                    />
              </View>
        </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: I think there may be any other issue related to your particular screen design. If possible please share your full view code and styles.